# I need to mix a numbered list with a bulleted list, validator says this is wrong

Tags: html, html-lists

As the subject says, I wrote this code to mix numbered list with bulleted list, it worked perfectly exactly the way I wanted it too but the validator says this is a no no so what's the proper way to do this? Below is my code:

```html
<ol>
       <li>Public, private &amp; religious schools programs and assemblies</li>
    <ul>
       <li>School assembly in elementary, middle, junior high, and high schools</li>
       <li>presentation to individual classes as part of the social studies or history curriculum at all grade levels</li>
       <li>Present video clips on various related topics followed by class/group discussions and activities.</li>
       <li>Work with youth groups/boy scouts/girl guides/YWCA</li>
       <li>After school programs</li>
       <li>Work with school-age after school programs</li>
       <li>Work with early childhood programs</li>
       <li>Community programs &amp; activities
     </ul>
   <li>Topics to include but not limited to -</li>
     <ul>
        <li>Prejudice</li>
        <li>Stereotyping</li>
        <li>Implicit bias</li>
        <li>Discrimination</li>
```

etc...

Answer (score 1):

Place the `ul` within the `li` no the `ol`:

```html
    <ol>
        <li>Public, private &amp; religious schools programs and assemblies
        <ul>
        <li>School assembly in elementary, middle, junior high, and high schools</li>
        <li>presentation to individual classes as part of the social studies or history curriculum at all grade levels</li>
        <li>Present video clips on various related topics followed by class/group discussions and activities.</li>
       <li>Work with youth groups/boy scouts/girl guides/YWCA</li>
       <li>After school programs</li>
       <li>Work with school-age after school programs</li>
       <li>Work with early childhood programs</li>
       <li>Community programs &amp; activities
     </ul>
       </li>
   <li>Topics to include but not limited to -
   <ul>
        <li>Prejudice</li>
        <li>Stereotyping</li>
        <li>Implicit bias</li>
        <li>Discrimination</li>
     </ul>
   </li>
</ol>
```